# I can not seem to make a TOR connection

Tags: tor

I tried using the direct and the custom Tor browser connection...
I tried disabling my virus and firewall programs, but I continue to get this
error message:
Tor failed to establish a Tor network connection.
Loading network status failed (no route to host - Then it gives a IP address.
I have an HP 15 Notebook laptop with OS windows 8.1

I hope to hear from somone really soon!!!

Comment: what happens when you boot from the tor live CD? does it work? that will rule out ISP on-premesis equipment, gateway firewalls, and ISP network operations as potential problems.

Comment: Is your system clock set to the correct time and date?

Comment: Did you try using bridges?